# SharePoint 2013 - get the internal name of a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, list-view, column

I use a SharePoint list to display a graphics in javascript and I want to get dynamically the name of the columns of my list and not write them in my code. Is there any way to that. To get my list, I use

```
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
```

I try to find a function to get the name/Title of the column but I don't find it.

Comment: Do you want to get internal name of list or name of list columns?

Comment: I want the name of list colum to use it as axis on my grap^h

Answer (score 2):

add to your code

```
clientContext.load(camlItems);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
                                Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args){}));        

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

   var listItemInfo = '';
   var listItemEnumerator = camlItems.getEnumerator();
   listItemEnumerator.moveNext()
   var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
   oListItem.get_fieldValues()
}
```

**get_fieldValues()** return list af all columsName (internalName)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the function return all data in the liste name of column and fielsd value. I try to find a function which return only the name of the column of my lits

Answer (score 1):

You can query the REST Service like this:

```
<weburl>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<listname>')/fields?$select=Name,Title
```

Example (excludes Hidden and ReadOnlyField fields):

```
var url = "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(' " + listTitle + " ')/fields?$select=Name,Title&$filter=Hidden eq false and ReadOnlyField eq false";
function getFieldPropertis(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for displays the title and internal name of all fields,
see 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185009.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_4

Comment: Thank you, i try the methods but il retrieve informations for all fields of the list not only the list column. Do you know a method or property i cna use to select only the column of my list.